# Is Backtrack 5 equal to Ubuntu + Security tools?

Tags: 10.04

I just ran backtrack 5 live cd, and it basically seems to me as if I had Ubuntu + the security tools backtrack includes...

Is there any difference between backtrack 5 and Ubuntu desktop 10.04? Apart from having the security tools...

Because if there isn't I don't see why you couldn't use backtrack 5 as a main OS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Backtrack Linux is a derivative of Ubuntu, and besides a bit of rebranding, it is just like an Ubuntu system with all the tools installed. Since it supports [installing to a hard disk](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/tutorials/backtrack-hard-drive-install/), you certainly can run it as your main operating system. Alternatively you could install an Ubuntu system and install whatever tools you want (all of them, if you want all of them). Furthermore, you could even [customize](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) an Ubuntu live CD or DVD (or live USB flash drive) yourself to include the tools included with Backtrack.

Comment: Besides being an Ubuntu derivative + security tools, [this faq](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ#Why_cant_I_just_add_the_Backtrack_repositories_to_my_Ubuntu_install_or_the_Ubuntu_repositories_to_my_Backtrack_install_.3F) says, it goes though some changes in kernel too. So, it may not be Ubuntu + security tools = Backtrack

Comment: I'd personally rather take a fully [documented kernel](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ#Where_is_the_Backtrack_manual_.3F) with strong user support community.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why you can't use Backtrack as your main is, especially if you do a lot of security work and would use the tools. Something like ubuntu is more convinent, however, because of its strong user community. Backtrack does not have a strong community because conventianally it is not used as a main OS.

Comment: But couldn't the advice found on Ubuntu forums & askubuntu be applied to Backtrack, since it is a derivative of ubuntu (as long as it does not deal with the sec. tools)?

Comment: Yes, even though sometimes it may yield unexpected results, e.g., kubuntu is different than ubuntu, and may act differently.

Answer (score 0):

I not agree that backtrack dont have a strong community, people there are very helpfull and help you with whatever it is.. It is of course not that good community as here, but its groing, and you can use most of the information here in backtrack, since it is Almost the same. After what i can understand it is "an extension" of ubuntu.. Correct me if i wrong. (the url: backtrack-linux.org )

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [this backtrack faq](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ#Why_cant_I_just_add_the_Backtrack_repositories_to_my_Ubuntu_install_or_the_Ubuntu_repositories_to_my_Backtrack_install_.3F)

> **Why cant I just add the Backtrack repositories to my Ubuntu install or the Ubuntu repositories to my Backtrack install ?**
>
> We highly recommend against this action because Backtrack tools are built with many custom features, libraries and kernel. We have no way of knowing how they will perform on a non Backtrack distribution, plus you will very quickly break your install.
>
> Also if you chose to add the ubuntu repositories to your Backtrack install, you will most certainly break your entire Backtrack install very quickly.
>
> We do a lot of testing to ensure that all packages in our repo will work together without causing problems.

I think, Backtrack gone through some very critical changes, so Ubuntu + security tools may not be equal a Backtrack. But, you may have a distro very close to it.